# D&D Tavern Revenue Optimization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, optimization

I am trying to figure out the best way for my group to get our maximum profit from a tavern we just got. The rules for determining the amount of money have been changed slightly by our DM. They are:
Roll a d100 ( 1-d10+1-percintile die (like a d10 but 10, 20,..,etc))
if the value is 10 or less then we have to pay the full amount of upkeep costs for the tavern (60 gold pieces). 
For 11-40 the tavern generated just enough to cover half it's expenses so we would owe 30 gold pieces.
For 41-60 then the tavern would simply cover it's expenses.
For 61-80 the tavern covers it's expenses and we will roll 6d6*6 profit.
For 81-90 we will roll 6d8* profit.
For 91+ we roll 6d10*6 profit. 
We also have the option of spending gold to promote the tavern; for each piece of gold we spend we can add 1 to the d100 roll. My first instinct was to simply spend 90 gold to make sure we will always get the highest tier of rolls. However, we can still roll poorly and lose money on our profit roll. Thus we will be spending too much on advertising. So what amount do we need to spend on advertising to be put in the highest profit bracket without spending so much that it cuts into our profit significantly. Perhaps a function can be built to be optimized? Or do I need to just run tons of Sims in Excel? Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Drew.

Comment: I am new to this site so I apologise for the poor formatting. I can certainly try.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Even though this question is related to mathematics, it might be met with more interest in [the RPG community](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: When you roll 6d10*6 does that mean you roll six ten sided dice, take the sum, and multiply by $6$?  I assume your 6d8* is missing a $6$ at the end.

Comment: What is a " 1-d10+1-percentile die"?  I don't understand what "like a d10 but 10, 20,..,etc" means.  Is this supposed to be a die with $10$ faces numbered "10,20,30,\dots?"

Comment: Could you try and explain the 6d8 stuff, or turn it into raw numbers?

Comment: @Ross Millikan yes we will roll 6 ten sided dice and then multiply the sum of the dice by 6.

Comment: @saulspatz:  you can think of it as one $100$ sided die.  I believe they actually roll two ten sided dice, one for the tens and one for the ones.  When I subtract $1$ I get to the range $0-99$, which is handier but not traditional

Comment: @saulspatz a percentile die is a die that has 10 sides with each side being multiples of 10 starting at 0 and going to 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

If the roll result is $1$ to $10$ you'll get $-60$ gold.

If the roll result is $11$ to $40$ you'll get $-30$ gold.

If the roll result is $41$ to $60$ you get $0$ gold.

If the roll result is $61$ to $80$ you get $6d6\cdot 6$ profit, expecting $6\cdot3.5\cdot6 = 126$ gold.

If the roll result is $81$ to $90$ you get $6d8\cdot 6$ profit, expecting $6\cdot4.5\cdot6 = 162$ gold.

If the roll result is $91$ or higher you get $6d10\cdot 6$ profit, expecting $6\cdot5.5\cdot6 = 198$ gold.

For every gold you spend, $1$ gets added to the roll result. I assume you spend the gold before rolling the die. Think of it like improving the $100$-sided die before you roll it by changing the numbers on the faces. But think of it like this: instead of increasing every face by one, you simply take the lowest face and increase it by $100$, putting its outcome into the highest profit bracket. The numbers on the die will end up being the same.

Now it's a simple matter of checking which faces are worth improving: Each face costs $1$ gold to improve, but lands only $1\%$ of the time, so the expected result when landing on the face should increase by at least $100$ gold from the upgrade to be worth the upgrade.

This is the case for faces $1$ to $10$ ($+258$ gold), $11$ to $40$ ($+228$ gold), and $41$ to $60$ ($+198$ gold), but not for the other faces ($+72$ gold, $+36$ gold, $+0$ gold respectively).

So to maximize your expected profit, you should invest exactly $60$ gold.

Comment: Why would the lowest face increase by 100? Wouldn't that only happen if I am spending 100 on advertising? I'm sorry I didn't understand your visualisation. Please feel free to show it to me from another angle if you wouldn't mind, I would like to understand your thought process.

Comment: By spending a coin on advertising, you effectively change a die with the numbers 1-100 to a die with the numbers 2-101, right? You can achieve that in practice by incrementing each face of the die, but you can also achieve that by just replacing the 1 with a 101, and that makes thinking about the probabilities easier.

Comment: How were you able to figure the profits for each group of upgrades? I understand, for example, the 1-10 group you remove the -60 because it's not possible to have a value that low anymore. Why do you then add 198 to the expectation? Shouldn't the expectation be a summation of all possible rolls averaged? As an example a 1-10 roll turns into a 11-20 so it's new expected profit is -30. Repeat for each category of rolls left. Am I on the wrong track here?

Comment: Remember, with the first gold we're only turning the $1$ into a $101$ and leaving all other faces of the die intact. So the outcome when landing on *that particular face*, which had an expected value of $-60$ gold, now has an expected value of $198$ gold.

Answer (score 0):

We can subtract $1$ from the roll and use only the first digit.  There are then ten possibilities and we can tabulate them
$$\begin {array}{r | r} roll & profit\\
0&-60\\
1,2,3&-30\\
4,5&0\\
6,7&6d6*6[126]\\
8&6d8*6[168]\\
9&6d10*6[198] \end {array}$$
where the square brackets have the expectation of the die roll.  It costs $10$ to move up one number in the roll.  Now we can compute the expectation with no advertising
$$\frac 1{10}\left(-60+3(-30)+2(0)+2(126)+168+198\right)=46.8$$
If you spend $10$ on advertising, you remove the $-60$ and add in a $198$, which is clearly a good idea.  It is worth $\frac 1{10}(258)=25.8$  Each additional $10$ you spend removes the current bottom profit and replaces it with $198$  You want to do that until the bottom profit is $98$ or greater, so you should spend $60$ on advertising.  The expected return is then
$$\frac 1{10}\left(126\cdot 2 + 168+198\cdot 7\right)-60=180.6-60=120.6$$

Comment: Does it matter that when rolling the d100 we will be using 2 dice? I know that when rolling a single die all sides have an equal chance of landing, but when we roll n dice doesn't it turn into a normal distribution (at least as n gets large)? Also when you are calculating the expectation why are you dividing the sum of the profits by 10? To make it a percentage value? Why does each 10 gold on advertising add 198? Thank you for your effort, your explanation is well written.

Comment: My understanding of rolling the d100 is that you roll two ten sided dice, with one being the tens and one being the ones.  In that case all numbers are equally probable.  In fact, you can just ignore the ones and roll a d10 that you interpret as $0$ to $9$ for this purpose.  You are correct that if you rolled two d50s the central numbers would be more probable, but not here.